# ASP.NET MVC4 Bundle a single file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

Is there a way to bundle a single file using the new bundling features in MVC4? I know bundling a single file doesn't make much sense but I'd like to use server-side minification and let MVC append a hash on to the end of the URL for caching purposes.

I've tried the `@Scripts.Url("~/Scripts/myscript.js")` but it doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 7):

Well, define a bundle containing only this file in your bundle config:

```
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myscript").Include("~/Scripts/myscript.js")
);
```

and then use it in your view by referencing it by name:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myscript")
```

Comment: Problem is our site is quite dynamic as we have many-many white labels so adding to the BundleTable in Global.asax file is not an option - is there a way to do it on the fly?

Comment: What do you mean by *on the fly*? Please provide more details. If you have many scripts you should consider grouping them in folders and bundling them per functionality.

Comment: It seems I can only register a bundle on application start-up. If I try the above code outside of my Global.axax file it doesn't work. I need to be able to "register" a bundle at any time during the application, does that make more sense?

Comment: When/why do you need to register bundles outside from your `Application_Start`?

Comment: Because our site is quite dynamic and we have hundreds of different white labels/skins and each "skin" has a bunch of Javascript files which change every day. It would be a nightmare to manage to put every single CSS/JS file in `AppStart`

Comment: Even if the site is not dynamic, if you have a ton of views, the bundle configuration will be just an endless list of one file CSS additions and one file js additions. A ton of plumbing code.

Answer (score 5):

I needed something like this, and here's what I came up with

On a view I can add a script or style with an HTML Helper.  These will each accept n number of parameters.

```
@Html.Style("~/Styles/someFile.css")
@Html.Script("~/Scripts/foo.js", "~/Scripts/bar.js")
```

So I created an extention to handle this for me. Here's what the class looks like.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {

        public static IHtmlString Script(this HtmlHelper helper, params string[] urls)
    {
        var bundleDirectory = "~/Scripts/bundles/" + MakeBundleName(".js", urls);
        var thisBundle = new ScriptBundle(bundleDirectory).Include(urls);
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(thisBundle);

        return Scripts.Render(bundleDirectory);
    }

    public static IHtmlString Style(this HtmlHelper helper, params string[] urls)
    {
        var bundleDirectory = "~/Styles/bundles/" + MakeBundleName(".css", urls);
        var thisBundle = new StyleBundle(bundleDirectory).Include(urls);
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(thisBundle);

        return Styles.Render(bundleDirectory);
    }

    private static string MakeBundleName(string type, params string[] urls)
    {
        var bundleSections = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in urls)
        {
            bundleSections.Add(item.Replace("~/", "").Replace("/", ".").Replace(type, ""));
        }

        return string.Join("+", bundleSections.ToArray());
    }
    }
}
```

---

## Caveats

This does hard code where the bundle "virtual directory" exists.  So if you have any relative paths to images or anything else in your files, they will break.  For our use case, this works fine for us for now.

The bundle names are auto-generated.  Again, this works for us, but it could be better.  I could see a simple improvement to this where you must provide a bundle path & name that would have a syntax like this: `@Html.Script("~/bundles/myBundleName","~/Scripts/foo.js", "~/Scripts/bar.js")`

---

I'd be happy to hear about any improvements anyone might have for this.

Comment: thanks I was just going down the same path and glad someone else went this route

Comment: you should also add `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: Isn't this code creating a new bundle for each page view? Or does MVC correctly handle duplicate bundles in BundleTable (i.e. if it has the same name, the old one would be dropped?). Also, is it multi-thread safe (if two requests try to access BundleTable.Bundles at the same time)

Comment: @youen I am not 100% sure on all of your questions, but i believe once a bundle is created, it will be cached.  So it should be created the first time it is visited, and then the caches version will be access any time afterwards.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Indeed, the browser will cache the file, no issue there. But on the server side, each time you call `BundleTable.Bundles.Add` you add a new entry in the table (I've checked that with the debugger). It's probably not a big hit, but maybe after thousand of requests it'll start using a bit of memory, and make the task harder for MVC to find a particular bundle in the list. The solution is simply to check the bundle doesn't already exist (same name) before adding a new one.

Answer (score 4):

I dont know, if I get you right, but you can add bundles any time you want to, just add it to the bundlecollection:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/myBundleName").Include(
            "~/Scripts/myscript.js"
            ));
```

I am not sure how you planing to include the bundle on client side, but after a bundle is registered you can get the url of the minified script file with this code:

```
string url = BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/myBundleName");
```

In my case I just get this url through an ajax request and create a script tag on client side. This way the script file will be minified and the url comes with an hash code, so the browser should cache it and when the bundle is changed should load the newer version.

I hope this is, what you intended to do.